# Conversion of excel formula to sql developer

Tags: excel-formula, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have excel data attached below.

[image]

the column S,T are calculated columns the formula is as below:

```
Column S =1/COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$3071,$D2,$J$2:$J$3071,$J2)
Column T =IF(COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$3071,$D2,$J$2:$J$3071,TEXT(DATE(YEAR(G2),MONTH(G2)+1,1),"MMM"))>0,1/COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$3071,$D2,$J$2:$J$3071,$J2),0)
```

I want these formulas to be converted to sql columns using Oracle SQL developer.